# Outputting a logo from the Wordpress Customiser

Tags: beginner, php, wordpress

I managed to solve a little problem I had myself by reading and modifying.
My code works, but as a novice I would like to ask if you could advise me of a cleaner way to achieve the same thing.

Things look a bit messy to me, so I'm sure there is probably a better way to do this.

This code simply outputs a logo from the Wordpress Customiser.

Any advice or direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
             $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod('custom_logo');
             $logo = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom_logo_id, 'full');
             if (has_custom_logo()) {
                 echo '<img src="' . esc_url($logo[0]) . '">';
             } else { ?>
                 <img src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo.png'>
<?php } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my  suggestions:

**There is no point of "fetching" the image url if `has_custom_logo` returns false.**

Instead, I would define `$logo` with a default value, then, if `has_custom_logo` is `true`, I would just rewrite it's value.

```
$logo = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/logo.png';

if(has_custom_logo()){
  $logos = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_theme_mod('custom_logo'), 'full');
  $logo  = reset($logos);
}

echo sprintf('<img src="%s" />', esc_url($logo));
```

I'm using [`reset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) method, it

> rewinds array's internal pointer to the first element and returns the
>   value of the first array element.

You can convert this to a method and use it in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks for that .. I've tested it and it is working exactly as it should, this is all a huge learning experience for me, so i greatly appreciate your assistance !